# prevent focus from leaving form fields

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

In my app, i have a login form like this

```
<div id="container">
  <form name="login" id="login" method="post" action="">
    <input name="email" type="text" class="label" id="email" placeholder="Enter email...">
    <input name="password" type="password" class="label" id="password" placeholder="Enter password...">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Login">
    <a href="register.html" class="sign">Sign Up</a>
  </form>
</div>
```

On touch devices, when I tap the screen, focus leaves the form fields (input,button,links). This happens on blackberry and android devices, haven't tried it on the iphone.

How can i prevent focus from leaving form fields? I'm building the app with phonegap.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? It's the expected behavior - tapping on the screen causes focus elsewhere. As a user, if I don't want to focus an input, I shouldn't have to. I don't know about blackberry/android, but I know in an iphone, when I click on an input, it zooms in and opens the keyboard. That would be very annoying if I purposely or accidently blur the textbox

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can prevent the user from clicking/selecting something else, but you can return the focus whenever it looses it. Simplest case:

```
<input onblur="this.focus()" type="text" name="text1"/>
```

But you can lock the user forever into that input unless you replace that with a function that evaluates if the current input still needs focus for some reason and otherwise not trigger the focus again.

If your problem is when the user does that to scroll the page, then you can try something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var last_selected_input;
    window.onscroll = function () {
        if (last_selected_input) {
            last_selected_input.focus();
        }
    }
</script>

<input type="text" name="text1" onfocus="last_selected_input = this" />
```

But you need to clear the variable `last_selected_focus` whenever a field is complete to avoid the persistent focus on each page scroll.

Comment: sorry, i meant form fields (input,links,button etc). i want the focus to always remain on either input, select, buttons or links. currently, if i tap an area outside the form, the focus disappears. i only want focus to change when i tap any of these fields.

Answer (score 0):

could be as simple as a variable that maintains the current input selected.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var selected;
    $('input').focus(function (e){
       selected = $(this).attr('id');
    });
    $('window').blur(function() {
       $('#selected').focus();
    });
});
```

Comment: yes, a variable that maintains the currently selected input will do. but this doesn't work.